# Display cannot be overriden

Tags: html, css

I have parts of page, which I doesnt want to display, when device display is smaller than 600px. I have css like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .smallScreenHidden {dispay:none}
}
```

Then I have one `<article>`, which has class, which says that it display as block. Problem is that I just cant override it, so it always displays. Doesn't matter in what order I write the classes, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Can we have a JSFiddle?

Comment: `display: block !important;`?

Comment: Could you please add some code relevant to the problematic element? The class style declaration and the markup for the `article` would be helpful. Also, you have a typo: `dispay : none`.

Comment: When you say "Doesn't matter in what order I write the classes" - where is it you're trying to write the classes in a different order?  Have you read about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)?

Comment: As @robertc says, guessing the specificity when you set the `<article>` to display as a block element is higher than the class specificity of `.smallScreenHidden {display:none}`

Comment: You should always double and triple check your code for typos before searching for something else...

Comment: Thx, Jones, if you post it as answer so I could accept it, it would be cool...:D

Comment: @user2665393 Are you sure that it's the `!important` and not just the correct spelled `display`. And btw. it's not really considered a good practice to use `!important`.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Exactly, this should be solved using specificity. Otherwise, it becomes impossible to cascade any further styles onto that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were a novice css user just as most of us are, you'd do:

```
display: block !important;
```

However, if you were an expert user and understand the importance of css specificity, you'd try to see why adding any number of classes doesn't help you override the display property of `<article>`

Now since I haven't seen your code and hence, I cannot give you a CSS Specificity solution, I recommend you check out this article on [CSS Specificity by Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/)